# Tuples as return values and parameters in classes

Tags: python, tuples

So I have a `Point` class which basically consists of X and Y coordinates, and I want to create a `Rectangle` class that is constructed from a point at its top left corner, its width and its height.

My idea is to pass the `Point` object as a parameter so the `Rectangle` class constructor will create its own `Point` attribute with the argument's `x` and `y` values, which should be returned as a tuple and assigned to the new object, but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, init_x, init_y):
        self.x = init_x
        self.y = init_y

    def get_point(self):
        return(self.x, self.y)

class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self,point,height,width):
        self.top_left = Point(point.get_point())

my_point = Point(1,2)
my_rectangle = Rectangle(my_point,2,2)
print(my_rectangle.top_left)
```

And this is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/programming/python/rectangle.py", line 70, in <module>
    my_rectangle = Rectangle(my_point,2,2)
  File "/Users/mac/Desktop/programming/python/rectangle.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.top_left = Point(point.get_point())
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'init_y'
```

Why is it not passing the two values as a tuple? Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unpack the tuple using the `*` unpacking syntax:

```
self.top_left = Point(*point.get_point())
```

Otherwise, the tuple returned by `get_point` will be treated as only one argument:

```
>>> def func(a, b):
...     return a, b
...
>>> func((1, 2))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: func() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'
>>> func(*(1, 2))
(1, 2)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are already passing a `Point` object here

```
my_rectangle = Rectangle(my_point,2,2)
```

so you don't have to create another `Point` like this

```
self.top_left = Point(point.get_point())
```

Simply do

```
self.top_left = point
```

The actual error is due to the fact that, `Point` class accepts two parameters in its `__init__`, but you are passing only one value, as a tuple.

```
Point(point.get_point())
```

Instead, you should be passing the values of `x` and `y`, by unpacking the tuple, like this

```
self.top_left = Point(*point.get_point())
```

Comment: I think he wants to copy the `point` so that changes to the passed point don't change his rectangle.